Calculating the variance of marginal effects for a GLM
I saw some posts on how to calculate the variances of marginal effects (e.g. Delta Method for Marginal Effects of Generalized Linear model , How to calculate the standard error of the marginal effects in interactions (robust regression)? , Computing and simulating average marginal effect standard error using Delta Method with reproducible codes). I wanted to try and and work through the math in more steps.
For a Generalized Linear Model (GLM):
$$ E[Y|X] = g^{-1}(X\beta) $$
$$ g(E[Y|X]) = X\beta $$
To find the marginal effect for any predictor $x_k$, we take the derivative:
$$ ME(x_k) = \frac{\partial E[Y|X]}{\partial x_k} = \frac{\partial g^{-1}(X\beta)}{\partial x_k} $$
Using chain rule:
$$ h(\beta) =  ME(x_k) = [g^{-1}]'(X\beta) \cdot \beta_k $$
For the variance of the marginal effect, we need to use the Delta method. The Delta method says that that for a function $h(\theta)$ of a random vector $\theta$, we can approximate $h(\theta)$ around a point $a$ using Taylor expansion:
$$ h(\theta) \approx h(a) + \nabla h(a)^T(\theta - a) $$
So we can now just use first principles to find the variance. Note that $Var[h(a)] = 0$ and $Var(a)=0$ :
$$ Var(h(\theta)) \approx \nabla h(\theta)^T \cdot Var(\theta) \cdot \nabla h(\theta) $$
Here, $h(\beta)$ is our marginal effect function: $ h(\beta) = [g^{-1}]'(X\beta) \cdot \beta_k $. We need to find $\frac{\partial h(\beta)}{\partial \beta_j}$ for all $j$:
Again using chain rule:
For $j = k$:
$$ \frac{\partial h(\beta)}{\partial \beta_k} = [g^{-1}]''(X\beta) \cdot x_k \cdot \beta_k + [g^{-1}]'(X\beta) $$
For $j \neq k$:
$$ \frac{\partial h(\beta)}{\partial \beta_j} = [g^{-1}]''(X\beta) \cdot x_j \cdot \beta_k $$
Taking all the unique derivatives (i.e. d/x1x2 is the same as d/x2x1), we can put them into a vector:
$$ \nabla h(\beta) = \begin{pmatrix}
[g^{-1}]''(X\beta) \cdot x_1 \cdot \beta_k \\
\vdots \\
[g^{-1}]''(X\beta) \cdot x_k \cdot \beta_k + [g^{-1}]'(X\beta) \\
\vdots \\
[g^{-1}]''(X\beta) \cdot x_p \cdot \beta_k
\end{pmatrix} $$
If we substitute this back into the original expression:
$$ Var(ME(x_k)) = \nabla h(\beta)^T \cdot Var(\beta) \cdot \nabla h(\beta) $$
And this is the kind of formula we can use for inference, e.g.:
$$ ME(x_k) \pm z_{\alpha/2} \sqrt{Var(ME(x_k))} $$
Did I do the math correctly?

I tried to verify this for a Poisson Regression:

$ g(μ) = \ln(μ) $
$ g^{-1}(z) = e^z $
$ [g^{-1}]'(z) = e^z $
$ [g^{-1}]''(z) = e^z $

The model becomes:
$$ E[Y|X] = g^{-1}(X\beta) = e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \beta_3x_3} $$
The marginal effect for $x_1$ using the earlier formula:
$$ ME(x_1) = [g^{-1}]'(X\beta) \cdot \beta_1 $$
Substituting in the derivative:
$$  h(\beta) =  ME(x_1) = e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \beta_3x_3} \cdot \beta_1 $$
We need to calculate each element of $\nabla h(\beta)$ individually:
For $j = 1$ (coefficient of interest):
$$ \frac{\partial h(\beta)}{\partial \beta_1} = e^{X\beta} \cdot x_1 \cdot \beta_1 + e^{X\beta} $$
For $j = 0$ (intercept):
$$ \frac{\partial h(\beta)}{\partial \beta_0} = e^{X\beta} \cdot \beta_1 $$
For $j = 2$:
$$ \frac{\partial h(\beta)}{\partial \beta_2} = e^{X\beta} \cdot x_2 \cdot \beta_1 $$
For $j = 3$:
$$ \frac{\partial h(\beta)}{\partial \beta_3} = e^{X\beta} \cdot x_3 \cdot \beta_1 $$
Putting everything together:
$$ \nabla h(\beta) = e^{X\beta}\beta_1 \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
x_1 + \frac{1}{\beta_1} \\
x_2 \\
x_3
\end{pmatrix} $$
The variance of the marginal effect is:
$$ Var(ME(x_1)) = \nabla h(\beta)^T \cdot Var(\beta) \cdot \nabla h(\beta) $$
Where $Var(\beta)$ is the 4×4 variance-covariance matrix of the coefficient estimates (i.e. this is coming from the MLE regression estimates after fitting the model):
$$ Var(\beta) = \begin{pmatrix}
\sigma^2_{\beta_0} & \sigma_{\beta_0\beta_1} & \sigma_{\beta_0\beta_2} & \sigma_{\beta_0\beta_3} \\
\sigma_{\beta_0\beta_1} & \sigma^2_{\beta_1} & \sigma_{\beta_1\beta_2} & \sigma_{\beta_1\beta_3} \\
\sigma_{\beta_0\beta_2} & \sigma_{\beta_1\beta_2} & \sigma^2_{\beta_2} & \sigma_{\beta_2\beta_3} \\
\sigma_{\beta_0\beta_3} & \sigma_{\beta_1\beta_3} & \sigma_{\beta_2\beta_3} & \sigma^2_{\beta_3}
\end{pmatrix} $$
Thus, the final expression is:
$$ Var(ME(x_1)) = (e^{X\beta}\beta_1)^2 \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 & x_1 + \frac{1}{\beta_1} & x_2 & x_3 \end{pmatrix} \cdot Var(\beta) \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ x_1 + \frac{1}{\beta_1} \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix} $$
